# Fuzzy logic in java

Tags: java, fuzzy-logic

I have been given a new project module which involves fuzzy logic. It is to determine different [Hydrometeors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precipitation_(meteorology)#Hydrometeor) using fuzzy logic method.I have very little idea about what fuzzy logic is. So I would like to have some advice from people who have already done projects using fuzzy logic in Java (like what are the basic programming strategies I can adopt).

I have come across a [fuzzy logc API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfuzzylogic/). People who have used it please comment on how useful it is.

Comment: Another article on SO: [What is fuzzy logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399618/what-is-fuzzy-logic)

Comment: I have used this API to teach Fuzzy Logic. It is simple and works very well. I recommend.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Fuzzy logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic) is an abstract concept that is completely independant of programming lanuages. The basic idea is that instead of boolean logic where any statement is either "true" or "false", you use a continuum where a statement can be anywhere between "100% true" and "0% true". This allows you to model some real-world scenarios much better than boolean logic, but of course requires different (more complex) rules for combining statements.

I have not used the API library you linked to, but it looks pretty well-maintained at first glance (it has been updated regularly, there is a recent release, and even an eclipse plugin).

Answer (score 2):

We developed a fuzzy logic matching algorithm in Java to find similarity in Strings.

https://github.com/intuit/fuzzy-matcher

In real life cases where a binary result is not enough and want to find similar matches, Fuzzy logic is widely useful.

For example if you have a set of names like

`["John Doe","Jack Miller","Jon Doe","J Doe","Miller J"]`

And want to group similar names together and find a probability on how similar they are

So running the library will group `["John Doe","Jon Doe","J Doe"]` together and group `["Jack Miller","Miller J"]` together

The GitHub page is well documented and see if that helps in understanding how fuzzy logic works.